# i need to write a program determines whether the inputted formula has equivalent set of parentheses

Tags: python, string

here is my code, it does run but the output is not the way it should be

```
formula = input("Enter a formula: ")
parenthesis = (formula.count("(,)"))
if parenthesis >= 1 :
    print ("You have enteread a complete formula.")
else:
    print ("You have incomplete set of parenthesis")
```

Comment: Hello, please show some exemple and what you except in order to give us a chance to help you properly.

Comment: one basic algorithm is when you go through the input one by one and if you encounter with '(' then increase a zero-based variable, when encounter with ')' decrease it and check if bigger or equals to zero. Finally you should get zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying in my head, but here is a simple way of doing it:

```
    formula = input("Enter a formula: ")
    open_brackets = formula.count("(")
    close_brackets = formula.count(")")
    if open_brackets == close_brackets:
        print("You have entered a complete formula.")
    else:
        print("You have incomplete set of parenthesis")
```

Comment: thank you! yes I need that code in it's simplest way thank you